# CoreData with MapKit unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, core-data, unrecognized-selector

I get the following error

```
2011-09-05 08:08:43.506 CaveConditions[7203:11903] -[NSManagedObject coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7471910
2011-09-05 08:08:43.507 CaveConditions[7203:11903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7471910'
```

This is where I call it

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cave" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude > 0) AND (longitude > 0)"];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL]];
```

It crashes at the addAnnotations line

In my Cave.h (It as a MKAnnotation delegate)

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

In my Cave.m

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [self.longitude doubleValue];
    return location;
}
```

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggest that `Cave` class is not registered as the class for the entity `Cave` in the data model. When you do a fetch, you get a generic NSManagedObject back instead of an instance of the `Cave` class.

Check the data model were has the field to put in the name for a custom NSManagedObject subclass. It is probably still set to the default.

Comment: Hm I am not quite getting what you mean sorry. I added a printscreen of the model part. What would I need to fill in there? And what does it change? As it works quite well in the tableview.

Comment: The field labeled `class`. It currently has the default value of NSManagedObject. You need to change that to `Cave`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Do I need to do it with all my Entinties? What is it for?

Comment: Entities and classes are separate. Entities describe the data model while the classes describe which objects will instantiate the actual data. The generic NSManagedObject class can instantiate any entity using associative storage but you don't get customized property names or accessors. If you want that, you need to create a custom NSManagedObject subclass, in this case `Cave`. You do need a custom subclass because you need to implement the MKAnnotation protocol.